# jQuery get only first id value from the loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

My code is:

```
<input id='edit' type='checkbox' />

while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($query_fetch)) 
    {        
       echo "     
       <input type='text' name='qty' id='qty' value='".$sum[0]."' disabled>
       "; 
    }

<script>
document.getElementById('edit').onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById('qty').disabled = !this.checked;
};
</script>
```

The problem is that when check the checkbox only the first row of the loop is effected. I want when checkbox is checked all input to be enabled.

Comment: it appears you're producing duplicated ids, remember that ids must be unique!

Comment: I try change this: `document.getElementById('qty').disabled = !this.checked;` to `document.getElementByTagName('input').disabled = !this.checked;` but also don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this in jQuery, change:

```
<input type='text' name='qty' id='qty' value='".$sum[0]."' disabled>
```

To:

```
<input type='text' name='qty' class='qty' value='".$sum[0]."' disabled>
```

And add the following code:

```
$('#edit').click(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $('.qty').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('.qty').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

Note: DOM object IDs should be unique. No two elements should have the same ID. You can assign the same class to multiple elements and identify them in javascript that way. Also, if these `input` elements are form elements you plan to process server side, you will need to name them differently or only the last value assigned will be available.

Comment: This work. When check the checkbox all inputs are enabled, but when uncheck again, they stay enabled.

Answer (score 0):

To do this in jQuery:

add class entry to the text fields:

```
<input type='text' class='qty' name='qty' id='qty' value='".$sum[0]."' disabled>
```

and then use the jquery

```
$( "#edit" ).click(function() {
     $( ".qty" ).each(function( index ) {
          if ($("#edit").is(':checked')) {
              $( this ).prop('disabled', false);
          } else {
              $( this ).prop('disabled', true);
          }
     });
 });
```

Comment: I'm not sure how well this would work. As one of the comments noted, all the checkboxes are named `qty`

Comment: actually #qty are text fields, and he wants to enabled/disable all the #qty text fields when he checks/unchecks #edit checkbox

Comment: Also effected only for first row in the loop.

Comment: Aleksandar understand me very well :)

Comment: ok, try this one, I beleive that jquery cant execute each on id, but can on class name, I edited my post

Comment: Give me error at this row: `$( this ).prop('disabled', false); );`

Comment: In mean time I fixed errors, you probably  copied old one, try this one

Answer (score 0):

First thing You don't use id for that much elements... id is unique for each element... 
here you can use class = qty .

you can get class values using jquery

```
$('.qty').eq(0).val();
```

still if you want to use id then you can concatenate any counter variable (i) to id

```
  echo "     
   <input type='text' name='qty"+i+"' id='qty' value='".$sum[0]."' disabled>
   ";
```

Comment: Sorry I'm not specialist with jquery and don't understand you very well. I put class to input element then where have to put `$('.qty').eq(0).val();`

Comment: $('.qty') means it selects all elements into array like having class qty  and .eq(0) is used to access that array location element...